# Simple Generics -- Is this possible Method<typeof(T)>()?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, recursion

I am attempting to create a generic mapping function that takes the values of a dictionary and its sub classes and maps them to the fields in T using reflection.  Within object T, there are sub objects that must be drilled into, and through recursion, it seems like a pretty simple concept.  However I am stuck -- and I'm not sure if it's a limitation of generics, or if it's something I am simply doing wrong.  Here's my function:

I call the first instance with the following.

```
OrderDetails readyOrder = Tools.MapStruct<OrderDetails>(order);
```

*XmlRpcStruct is a dictionary, and the sub classes are *always* XmlRpcStruct's -- which conta

```
    public static T MapStruct<T>(XmlRpcStruct xmlRpcStruct) where T : new()
    {
        T map = new T();
        foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in xmlRpcStruct)
        {
            XmlRpcStruct entryStruct = (XmlRpcStruct)entry.Value;
            foreach (DictionaryEntry subEntry in entryStruct)
            {
                if (subEntry.Value.GetType() != typeof(XmlRpcStruct))
                {
                    var prop = map.GetType().GetField(subEntry.Key.ToString());
                    prop.SetValue(map, subEntry.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    var prop = map.GetType().GetField(subEntry.Key.ToString());
                    ERROR -->prop.SetValue(map, MapStruct<prop.GetType()> (subEntry.Value));
                }
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
```

For example, I could have a dictionary with the following data:

**Key----Value**

First--John

Last---Smith

Age----45

Address-Dictionary Object

*...and an object:*

obj.First (string)

obj.Last  (string)

obj.Age      (int)

obj.Address  (AddressType)

I'm using the type in the object to determine what the Dictionary object from the name value pair should be cast as.

I need to be able to dynamically get the type of the sub item within my dictionary and recursively call the same function.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: So, what is `subEntry.Value`?

Comment: I don't know any C#, yet I know one thing: Generics are a compile-time concept: When compiling, all types of ingoing objects are checked and all types of outoing objects are casted - from there Generics no longer exist and once compiled, there will be no clue as to the type of the objects in question. I think typeof is not handled at compile time, so it makes little sense (or might be impossible, I don't know) to use it in Generics.

Comment: Jasper: You're wrong. That's true for Java Generics and C++ templates, but not C# generics. How else can you instantiate a generic function that's compiled in an assembly?

Comment: @DeadMG: I thought it was true for Generics as a concept (I would be interested to find out how C# implements Generics then), but I may be wrong there. However, you are absolutely wrong when it comes to C++ templates - there is a reason why they aren't called Generics and that's because they work in an entirely different way (having other weaknesses, strengths and possibilities).

Comment: @Jasper: I know exactly how C++ templates work. They are compile-time only. I never stated anything otherwise. C# Generics are not.

Comment: @DeadMG: You have a funny way of showing how well you know how C++ templates work. One could call it compile-time only, but that's misleading. Actually a different class/function (instantiation) is made for each different data type a template is made. At run-time it is no longer visible that it once was a template, so you could say it is compile-time only. However, as there actually is a difference between a list<int> and a list<float> at runtime, it's not really accurate.

Comment: @DeadMG: Either way, this is a horribly inappropriate place for a discussion like this, so I will no longer be participating in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not wrap it? It's using reflection anyway...

```
public static T MapStruct<T>(XmlRpcStruct xmlRpcStruct) where T : class, new()
{
    return (T)MapStructInternal(typeof(T), xmlRpcStruct);
}

private static object MapStructInternal(Type t, XmlRpcStruct xmlRpcStruct)
{
    object map = t.GetConstructor(new Type[0] ).Invoke(new object[0]);
    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in xmlRpcStruct)
    {
        XmlRpcStruct entryStruct = (XmlRpcStruct)entry.Value;
        foreach (DictionaryEntry subEntry in entryStruct)
        {
            if (subEntry.Value.GetType() != typeof(XmlRpcStruct))
            {
                var prop = map.GetType().GetField(subEntry.Key.ToString());
                prop.SetValue(map, subEntry.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                var prop = map.GetType().GetField(subEntry.Key.ToString());
                prop.SetValue(map, MapStructInternal(map.GetType(),(XmlRpcStruct)subEntry.Value));
            }
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Throught Reflection, you can create a generic *class* (and an object of the class) at runtime, however, I don't believe you can create a generic *method*.  SO, if you change you code from

```
 public static T MapStruct<T>(XmlRpcStruct xmlRpcStruct) where T : new()  {...}
```

to

```
 static class Mapper<T> where T : new() 
 {
      public T MapStruct(XmlRpcStruct xmlRpcStruct) {....}
 }

  var mapper = new Mapper<OrderDetails>();
  OrderDetails readyOrder = mapper.MapStruct<OrderDetails>(order);
```

Then you should be able to make it work.

Comment: `MethodInfo` does have a `MakeGenericMethod` method that will do the trick, if provided the method, in this case by `MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod`.  The resulting `MethodInfo` would have be invoked dynamically.